# Can't figure out why it isn't working, anymore

Tags: javascript, html

So been trying to learn more javascript, by doing small projects that are simple but are starting stuff. One of the projects is a to-do app which for some people is really simple, but for me as a starter it's quite complex.

Now here is the thing, I had it working for the most part, I can add stuff, and one thing only HALF works, I wrote a bit that adds a X button to a li element. Now it works when I put the li element in the HTML page itself, but when it's added through javascript, it doesn't.

There is no error, it was working before but for some reason it.. broke.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>To Do App!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/stylesheet.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="h1Div">
        <h1> To-do app! </h1>
        <input type="text" id="inputForList">
        <input type="button" id="btnInput" value="Add me!" onclick="btnFunction()">
    </div>

    <ul id="ulSection">
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
    </ul>
    <script src="Scripts/javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is the HTML page, super simple.

```
//Adds li element with input from a textbox
function btnFunction(){
    var cLi = document.createElement("li");
    var inpList = document.getElementById("inputForList").value;
    var txtNode = document.createTextNode(inpList);
    cLi.appendChild(txtNode);

    //Check to see if anything is filled in, otherwise send message. And 'appends' it to the list item
    if(inpList === ''){
        alert("Voeg wat toe!");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ulSection").appendChild(cLi);
    }
    // Reset value of Textbox to ""
    document.getElementById("inputForList").value = "";
}

//Sets a 'x' on every element.
var ulList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var i;
for(i = 0; i < ulList.length; i++){
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    var xBtn = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
    span.className = "Done";
    span.appendChild(xBtn);

    ulList[i].appendChild(span);
}
```

And this is the Javascript.

As stated, it worked before. But for some reason, now the bottom section, the X button (\u00D7) part, it sn't working on the 'new stuff' that I add through the text input..

Comment: Very simple: You need to wrap your bottom code in a function, so it can be conveniently called at anywhere/anytime. Run the function every time a new item is added to the list. Currently your bottom code is only run once: on initial load of the app.

Comment: Also yeah this answer is valid yeah. Seems I forgot to do that, still weird that it worked earlier somehow but now I know :)! Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is good, you just need to do the same thing you did in

```
  var ulList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < ulList.length; i++) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    var xBtn = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
    span.className = "Done";
    span.appendChild(xBtn);

    ulList[i].appendChild(span);
  }
```

in `btnFunction()` (with the exception of the `for` loop, which isn't needed in the function, as only one element is added at a time). The reason for this is your code only runs when the page is loaded, or when it is specifically told to run (in your case, on a button click). if you just create an element the js doesn't know to update it with an `x`, you have to tell it to do so.

```js
//Adds li element with input from a textbox
function btnFunction() {
  var cLi = document.createElement("li");
  var inpList = document.getElementById("inputForList").value;
  var txtNode = document.createTextNode(inpList);
  cLi.appendChild(txtNode);

  //Check to see if anything is filled in, otherwise send message. And 'appends' it to the list item
  if (inpList === '') {
    alert("Voeg wat toe!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ulSection").appendChild(cLi);
    var ulList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
      var span = document.createElement("span");
      var xBtn = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
      span.className = "Done";
      span.appendChild(xBtn);
      ulList[ulList.length-1].appendChild(span);
    }
    // Reset value of Textbox to ""
    document.getElementById("inputForList").value = "";
  }

  //Sets a 'x' on every element.
  var ulList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < ulList.length; i++) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    var xBtn = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
    span.className = "Done";
    span.appendChild(xBtn);

    ulList[i].appendChild(span);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>To Do App!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="h1Div">
    <h1> To-do app! </h1>
    <input type="text" id="inputForList">
    <input type="button" id="btnInput" value="Add me!" onclick="btnFunction()">
  </div>

  <ul id="ulSection">
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
  </ul>
  <script src="Scripts/javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Alright so that seems to work, which is nice. But I do have a question, cause as I stated, earlier today with the exact code I posted, it worked. Like when I added stuff, it added the X, the only thing I changed was in a css file. I guess this works but I have no idea why it 'broke' in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure it was working? It doesn't look like it would work.